# Applied Linear Algebra | Linear Dependent Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, education

Question: [image]

My response:

[image]

Am I solving the above question correctly? Or am I on the wrong path? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please use [LaTeX Markup](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of images. But from what I could decipher your answer seems to be correct.

Comment: Yes, you are solving it correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I got a bit frustrated with typing and not getting exactly how it should look like so I just wrote down. I do apologize, I am completely new with all this forum stuff. I do appreciate the help. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your method works fine.

Here's another suggestion, which you may or may not find easier. We are looking for numbers $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, such that

$$\lambda_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}+\lambda_2\begin{bmatrix}-5 \\ -8 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ -5 \\ k \end{bmatrix}.$$

The first two rows of this vector equation gives two linear equations in two unknowns $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Thus you can solve the two equations:

$$\lambda_1 - 5\lambda_2 = 3,$$
$$3\lambda_1 - 8\lambda_2 = -5.$$

With standard methods, you get $\lambda_1 = -7$ and $\lambda_2 = -2$. From the third row of the vector equation above, you can plug in these values for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ to obtain $k$:

$$k = \lambda_1\cdot (-1) + \lambda_2\cdot 2 = -7\cdot(-1) + (-2)\cdot 2 = 7 - 4 = 3.$$

Comment: Thank you. It actually made more sense than my own work.